# Trying to assign a cell values, but keep reminding "type mismatch"

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks for answers. I realize where I made mistakes so I modified a little bit but a new error reminder popped up. It keeps reminding me "expected :(" on "Instra = Instrb + 2" row.

```
Option Explicit

Sub separate()

Dim instrb As Integer
Dim Instra As Integer
Dim i As Integer

i = 2

Do Until Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A") = ""
instrb = InStr(Cells(i, "A").Text, "pm")
Instra = Instrb + 2
    Cells(i, "B").Value = Right(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A"), (Len(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A")) - Instra))
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

---

I am a newbie on coding so I know my work looks stupid. What I am trying to do is copy all the words on right side of "pm" in column A and paste into column B. However it keeps reminding me "type mismatch". I think I am doing right so not sure what is going on.

```vb
Sub separate()
    Dim instrb As Integer
    Dim Instra As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 2

    Do Until Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A") = ""
        instrb = InStr(Cells(i, "A").Text, "pm")
        Instra = Instrab + 2
        Cells(i, "B").Value = Right(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A"), Len(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A") - Instra) + 2).Text
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Instrab`? Do you have `Option Explicit` at the top of your module? Also, what line is throwing the error?

Comment: Since you've declared your `instrb` and `Instra` variables as `Integer` (numeric) you can't assign string (text) values to them. I think that's what is happening here

Comment: @TimStack but `InStr` returns a number ;) Where did the OP try to assign text? I think the issue is here `Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A") - Instra` and `Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A")` does not return a number. And the `Right` function has no `.Text`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Totally missed that, must be the heat as it's 30c in my room

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub separate()
    Dim instrbb As Integer
    Dim instra As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 2

    Do Until Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A") = ""
        instrbb = InStr(Cells(i, "A").Text, "pm")
        instra = instrbb + 2
        Cells(i, "B").Value = Right(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A").Text, (Len(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A")) - instra + 1))
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

But you can simplify with:

```
Sub separate()
    Dim instrbb As Integer
    Dim instra As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim s As String

    i = 2
    With Worksheets(1)
        Do Until .Cells(i, "A") = ""
            s = .Cells(i, "A").Text
            .Cells(i, "B").Value = Split(s, "pm")(1)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

**NOTES:**

1. avoided using Instrb as a variable as it is a pre-defined VBA function
2. corrected simple math errors in parsing the string
3. as others have mentioned, it would be wise to use `Long` in place of `Integer`
4. as others have mentioned, it would be wise to use `Option Explicit`

Comment: Consider `i As Long` since it is row counting and Excel has more rows than fit into `Integer`.

Comment: Your code is great and works perfectly on my computer!  However I am still confused why name the variable as instrbb instead of my instrb? It seems like it doesn't work with instrb and keeps reminding "expected :(". Besides I need copy your code to make sure it works. If I type it manually follow your codes, it still doesn't work, reminding me "invalid procedure call or argument" on the longest row even though I typed the exactly same as yours. @Gary's Student

Comment: Actually the [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) returns a `Long` too :)

Comment: Actually I am confused with the "+1" in "Len(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A")) - instra + 1". Mind elaborating? @Gary's Student

Comment: As a side note, declaring variables as integers on 32-bit systems does not have any advantages over `Long` and [may even hurt performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/10540017).